# Centos install exim 4.94 dependency error

Tags: centos, rpm, dependencies

I am trying to install exim's specific version on centos... yet the log is like below.
To me it seemed like an openssl issue i check it but it seems installed already.

```
[root@vmi1522973 ~]# rpm -ivh exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                
error: Failed dependencies:                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                
        libcrypt.so.2()(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                      
        libcrypt.so.2(XCRYPT_2.0)(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            
        libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                   
        libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                      
        libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                      
        libgsasl.so.7()(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                      
        libgsasl.so.7(LIBGSASL_1.1)(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                          
        libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.29)(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                
        libnsl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                        
        libnsl.so.2(LIBNSL_1.0)(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                              
        libopendmarc.so.2()(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                  
        libperl.so.5.30()(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                    
        libspf2.so.2()(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                       
        libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                      
        libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                         
        libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                         
        perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.30.3) is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                 
        rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64
```

How to fix these problems especially the one for with `rpmlib`?

Comment: What is the OS and release version?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Comment: Is the machine connected to the internet? If so, then `yum install exim`.

Comment: okay buy i want to install version 4.93 or 4.94.... that is what i am after @NasirRiley

Comment: also, either way it says package exim is not available... but as i said i need specific versions

Answer (score 3):

You say you are installing onto CentOS 7, but the `exim-4.94-2.eln102.x86_64.rpm` package you have looks to have been built for CentOS 8 due to the requirement for `libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)`.

You would be much better off trying to install this package onto CentOS 8 than trying to upgrade `libc` on your CentOS 7 machine.

After looking at `exim` packages available for CentOS 7, there is [`exim-4.96.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/exim-4.96.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm) packaged in the EPEL repository.

Once you enable to EPEL repository for CentOS 7 (`yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`), you should be able to `yum install exim` and get version 4.96.2

If you absolutely must install Exim version 4.94, then you should look for a package [built for CentOS 7](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/7.8/x86_64/Packages/e/exim-4.94-1.el7.x86_64.rpm).

Comment: `exim-4.94-2.eln102` is actually a [build of exim for Fedora ELN back in 2020](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1531477).  ELN is a rebuild of Fedora Rawhide with RHEL macros and build options to ensure readiness for the next RHEL major version bootstrap.  It doesn't look like exim ever made it into CentOS Stream and RHEL, so it must have been dropped from ELN at some point.

You're 100% correct on using older EPEL builds to solve this specific request.